# How to test a void method that prints on console in jUnit?

Tags: java, junit

I use a factory pattern. I have 3 currencies: dollars, RON and euro. In each of this classes i have the same function, print, with different output:

```
public void print() {
    System.out.println("I printed dollars!");

}

     public void print() {
    System.out.println("I printed euro!");}
```

In my factory class, i have a method that return a new Object of currency type:

```
    public Valuta getValuta(String numeValuta){
    if(numeValuta == null){
        return null;
    }
    if(numeValuta.equalsIgnoreCase("dolar")){
        return new Dolar();
    }
    if(numeValuta.equalsIgnoreCase("euro")){
        return new Euro();
    }
    if(numeValuta.equalsIgnoreCase("lei")){
        return new Lei();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Now, in my Test class, i tried testing this:

```
    FabricaBani fabrica = new FabricaBani();
    Valuta valuta = fabrica.getValuta("dolar");
    valuta.tipareste();
    assertEquals("I printed dollars!", valuta.print());
```

I get an error that says that i cannot test a String with a void. I tried putting .toString after valuta.print, but i am not allowed.

Comment: Basically, you've written code that is hard to test. If you changed your class to override `toString()` instead, or have `print` accept a `Writer` for example, then it would be easier to test.

Comment: Try to return the String value in your `print()` method after the `System.out.println()`. Your assert will use the returned value and print it to the console output.

Comment: @Jon Skeet I'm sorry but i didn't understand you. Can you be a little more specific?

Comment: I think a different way to say it is, instead of having your method write directly to the console, you should have it return the value it is about to write (or take in what it needs to use for writing), and have some other code (either a `Writer` or the calling method) do the output instead. That way, you can step in and test what is being output, in the same way as the code which actually does the output.

Comment: Basically, you're "decoupling" the parts which (a) generate the output text, and (b) actually output the generated text to the console, so you can test between them.

Comment: I totally agree with Jon Skeet! That code isn't designed very well. It's not good to read, not good to test, and really bad to maintain in terms of OOP. I'd also go with overriding the toString-method!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method valuta doesn't return anything, that's why valuta.print() can't be the String you output to the console.

If you want to test the value, you could refactor your method to return the String instead of outputting it; then you'd print the returned String in the method that calls print().

```
public String print() {
    return "I printed dollars!";
}

 public void print() {
  return "I printed euro!";
 }
```

Then, you'd call the print like this to output to console

```
System.out.println(valuta.print());
```

You can maybe rename the print method to getCurrency to better express what the method does.

Comment: Thank you. I had to change almost every class, but it worked!

Comment: You are a genius. Thank you so much. I am feeling silly now.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a test that calls `setOut` to capture the printout, like this:

```
private static void test() {
    System.out.println("Hello, world!");
}
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    String res = null;
    PrintStream originalOut = System.out;
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream(100);
        PrintStream capture = new PrintStream(os);
        // From this point on, everything printed to System.out will get captured
        System.setOut(capture);
        test();
        capture.flush();
        res = os.toString();
    } finally {
        System.setOut(originalOut);
    }
    System.out.println("Captured output: "+res);
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/DiwtFT)

This is far from ideal, and should be used only when you have no other way to test the relevant functionality - for example, when you have no control over a portion of the code that does the output.

On the other hand, this approach lets you test side effects of code that must do some printing, so it may be relevant in situations when your tests must ensure output to `System.out`.

Comment: You can use the SystemOutRule of the [System Rules](http://stefanbirkner.github.io/system-rules/) library instead of implementing the code by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

A good alternative for this case could be to **extend the Dollar** (or one individual inheriting class) for testing.  Then, when calling the print() method, you could store the last string printed.

```
// Inside class extending Dollar, for example
// public class TestDolar extends Dollar
@Override
public void print() {
  _printedMessage = Valuta.DOLLAR_MESSAGE
}
```

which may mean you could **store the print messages in Valuta**, or in the individual classes.

```
//Inside Dollar
public void print() {
  System.out.println(Valuta.DOLLAR_MESSAGE);
}

//Inside Valuta
public static final String DOLLAR_MESSAGE = "I printed dollars!";
```